# ClearInterval not stopping

Tags: jquery

I have the following JQuery code:

```
JModel.ClipThumbs.Clip.prototype = {
    interval: null,

    setThumb: function(src) {
        this.mainThumb.src = src;
    },
    mouseEntered: function(el) {
        var temp        = this;
        var x           = 0;
        this.interval   = setInterval(function() {
            if (x >= temp.galleryImgs.length) {
                x = 0;
            }
            // set main thumb
            temp.setThumb(temp.galleryImgs[x].src);
            // increment for the display (0/7 being bad looking to users)
            x++; 
            // update image count display
            $(temp.clipCount).html(""+x+"/"+temp.galleryImgs.length); 
        }, 1000);
    },
    mouseLeft: function(el) {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
};
```

When I leave the gallery rotation doesn't stop

Ideas?

**EDIT**: the fix was:

```
jQuery(this.mainThumb)
    .bind('mouseenter', jQuery.proxy(this.mouseEntered, this))
    .bind('mouseleave', jQuery.proxy(this.mouseLeft, this));
```

The `mouseleave` had to have a `jQuery.proxy` with this bound also to access this.

Comment: Instead of repeating `JModel.ClipThumbs.Clip.prototype.` multiple times, do it like so: `JModel.ClipThumbs.Clip.prototype = { setMainThumb: function() { ... }, galleryImageMouseEnter: function() { ... }, ... }`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it looks much neater now!

Comment: Be careful. When you put a property into the prototype, then this property is shared by all instances. Usually, you want to put methods into the prototype. But in the above code, you also put the `interval` property into the prototype, which means that every instance will share this same property. You probably don't want to do that, right?

Comment: I don't think it would matter either way as its mouse on and mouse off.

You can test it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/XTNr6/3/

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
clearInterval( this.interval );
```

In the `galleryImageMouseEnter` method, you are defining the `interval` property on the instance object. Therefore, in the `galleryImageMouseLeave` method, you have to write `this.interval` to reference that property.

Comment: Hello, I have updated the code, it doesnt stop the interval, if I console log this.interval in the mouseleave method it comes as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The interval property is only defined in the function scopes, they cannot reach each other. Defining an interval property outside in the prototype, lets you reach it from both functions.

```
JModel.ClipThumbs.Clip.prototype = {

    // Define an interval object property
    interval: null,

    setMainThumb: function(src) {
        this.mainThumb.src = src;
    },
    galleryImageMouseEnter: function(el) {
        var temp        = this;
        var x           = 0;
        this.interval   = setInterval(function() {
            if (x >= temp.galleryImgs.length) {
                x = 0;
            }
            temp.setMainThumb(temp.galleryImgs[x].src);
            x++;
        }, 1000);
    },
    galleryImageMouseLeave: function(el){
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
};
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, I've updated my first post, I tried putting interval as you described and it still doesnt stop it.